# Problems with solving $x\left (-1-2xy\right){y}'=2y\left (1+xy\right)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the equation below

$$x\left (-1-2xy\right){y}'=2y\left (1+xy\right)$$

These are the steps that I took

First I rearranged the equation
$${y}'=\frac{2y\left (1+xy\right)}{x\left (-1-2xy\right)}$$

Then I substituted $y$ for $y=\frac{u-1}{x}$ where $u$ is a function of $x$. Thus, ${y}'$ become

$${y}'=\frac{{u}'x-u+1}{x^{2}}$$

Next, I put these values into the initial equation and got

$$\frac{{u}'x-u+1}{x^{2}}=\frac{2\frac{u-1}{x}\left (1+x\frac{u-1}{x}\right)}{x\left (-1-2x\frac{u-1}{x}\right)}$$

$$\frac{{u}'x-u+1}{x^{2}}=\frac{2(u-1)u}{x^{2}(1-2u)}$$

$${u}'x-u+1=\frac{2(u^{2}-u)}{1-2u}$$
$${u}'x=\frac{2(u^{2}-u)}{1-2u}+u-1$$

$${u}'x=\frac{u-1}{1-2u}$$

$$\frac{1-2u}{u-1}{u}'=\frac{1}{x}$$

$$\frac{1-2u}{u-1}du=\frac{1}{x}dx$$

Then I just took the integral of both sides

$$ \int \frac{1-2u}{u-1}du= \int \frac{1}{x}dx$$

$$ -2(u-1)-ln(u-1)+C_{2}= ln(x)+C_{1}$$

Since $u=yx+1$ the final result that I got was

$$ -2(yx+1-1)-ln(yx+1-1)= ln(x)+C_{1}$$

$$ -2yx-ln(yx)= ln(x)+C_{1}$$

I stopped here because I was not sure what to do next. Any suggestions on how to get the final answer?

Comment: You could use the Lambert-W function, at least to formally reach an explicit solution.

Comment: So there's no other way to express the solution? Other than using the Lambert-W function.

Comment: No, does not look like it. You get $(2xy)e^{(2xy)}=\frac{C}{x}$, so inverting to $y=\frac1{2x}W(\frac{C}{x})$ is the natural next step.